# Dynamically add rows to table in sqlite (using objective c)

Tags: database, sqlite

Just like when adding a new contact in the ios contact app, (like [this](http://postimg.org/image/oqfsbjybd/)) you can add multiple phone numbers, I'm trying to add those new numbers to sqlite db. Here's how:

I'm trying to dynamically add new rows to a table in sqlite, using objective c. I so far created this (in macs terminal):

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE phone_numbers(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    contact_id INTEGER REFERENCES contacts(id)
);
```

Is it correct that every time the user adds a new phone number, it should create a new row `phoneNumber text` inside the table of `phone_numbers`? If so, then is it okay that the there will be multiple rows name the same thing? (`phoneNumber`)

Comment: Don't you need a column in the `phone_numbers` table for the actual phone number?

Comment: Yes. But there will be more than 1 phone number. (I don't know how many)

Comment: You add a record for each phone number.

Comment: Do you mean a new column for each number (in the table of `phone_numbers`)?

Comment: No, I meant what I said. You add a row for each phone number. The table will only have one "phone number" column (which you need to add along with the other two columns).

Comment: Oh... got it. Thanks! Can you post that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `phone_numbers` table to have a `phone_number` column (as `text`).

Then when you add a contact with more than one phone number, you add a row to the `phone_numbers` table for each phone number. So each new row gets one of the contact's phone numbers.